# How can i solve Excel VBA Oracle Connection error 3706

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm using this code with vb.net and I'm successfully connecting to the  database.
However when I try the same code in Excel I'm getting error "run time error 3706".
I tried all answers about this problem but I haven't been able to solve my problem.

Here is my code:

```
 Public cn_oracle As New OleDbConnection("Provider=msdaora;Data Source=****;User Id=****;Password=****;")
```

Answer (score 0):

msdaora is outdated, did you install Oracle drivers on that machine?
If so, you can try to use "OraOLEDB.Oracle" as provider.